# SSH, OpenVPN and connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, routing, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server configured to listen on UDP ports. Recently I noticed that I can't access some hosts in my network via SSH. Here's my setup:

- **tun0** - the openvpn tunnel on the server
- **enp2s0** - the ethernet adapter connected to Verizon router
- bunch of other servers connected to the same Verizon router

the IP address of tun0 is **10.9.0.1**

my IPTABLES is dead simple:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Oct 22 01:16:10 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [61507:19615383]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [13925:2889584]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [58841:13675304]
-A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 22 01:16:10 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Oct 22 01:16:10 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [222:18139]
:INPUT ACCEPT [43:2580]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [153:10471]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [238:15571]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 22 01:16:10 2016
```

one of the servers I can't **connect to** has the IP address **192.168.1.157**

the IP address of the client host that is connected via VPN is **10.9.0.100**

I can ping **192.168.1.157** from **10.9.0.100**. I can ping **10.9.0.100** from **192.168.1.157**

I started `nc -l -s 192.168.1.157 -p 2222` on **192.168.1.157** and tried to connect to port **2222** from **10.9.0.100** - that worked, I can type in text on **10.9.0.100** and see it appearing on other terminal - and then `read(net): Connection reset by peer` is printed on **192.168.1.157** and netcat terminates. If I connect to the netcat and try to type something on **192.168.1.157** - then nothing appears in the console on **10.9.0.100** and I get this `read(net): Connection reset by peer` on **192.168.1.157**

I can telnet to port **22** on **192.168.1.157** from **10.9.0.100** but I can't see the standard prompt of SSH server.

However if I try to connect to the server with the SSH client, I can see in the logs of the server that

```
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[626]: debug1: Forked child 995.
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[995]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[995]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[995]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[995]: debug1: getpeername failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
Oct 22 01:26:56 http-1-1 sshd[995]: debug1: ssh_remote_port failed
```

if I do `tcpdump -i eth0 port 22 and src host 10.9.0.100` on **192.168.1.157** and try to connect via ssh from **10.9.0.100** i see this in /var/log/auth.log

```
01:39:45.486123 IP 10.9.0.100.53546 > http-1-1.fios-router.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1176047909, win 29200, options [mss 1368,sackOK,TS val 8701042 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:39:45.562909 IP 10.9.0.100.53546 > http-1-1.fios-router.home.ssh: Flags [.], ack 324252195, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 8701066 ecr 286207], length 0
01:39:45.567772 IP 10.9.0.100.53546 > http-1-1.fios-router.home.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 0:21, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 8701066 ecr 286207], length 21
01:39:45.641442 IP 10.9.0.100.53546 > http-1-1.fios-router.home.ssh: Flags [R], seq 1176047931, win 0, length 0
01:39:45.839893 IP 10.9.0.100.53546 > http-1-1.fios-router.home.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 0:21, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 8701150 ecr 286207], length 21
```

What do I miss here? I guess there's some packet filtering happening in place, but not sure if I screwed up my iptables, or that Verizon FiOS router screws up some packets while processing those. I don't see where that RST packet really comes from.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `tun0` with `enp2s0` in the POSTROUTING chain rule.
And the rule in the FORWARD chain seems unnecessary.

Comment: Actually I realized that if I ping the host first - then I can connect to it tight after that.